# Jmeter TCP Sampler- getting response data blank with status code 200

Tags: tcp, jmeter

Trying TCP sampler for sending text message to server over TCP and expecting response ack for the same.
getting request success.but response data is blank(expecting response acknowledgment).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Given you have connection established already it automatically means that JMeter has received SYN-ACK from the AUT (application under test) and it has received ASK from JMeter.

[TCP handshake looks like](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/):

1. JMeter a TCP **SYN**chronize packet to AUT
2. AUT receives JMeter's SYN
3. AUT sends a **SYN**chronize-**ACK**nowledgement
4. JMeter receives AUT SYN-ACK
5. JMeter sends **ACK**nowledge
6. AUT receives ACK

Java doesn't have raw sockets support, neither does JMeter so if you want to fully control TCP messages flow and be able to see the headers and flags - you will need to go a level deeper using i.e. [jNetCap](http://jnetpcap.com/) library from [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

You might also be interested in [How to Load Test TCP Protocol Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter) article which explains how you can test your TCP server performance with JMeter and [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler easier to use than JMeter's TCP Sampler